# What do the Raphael object attributes "x" and "y" mean?

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I expected this to be 100% a no-brainer, but as it turns out, I cannot figure out what the *x* and *y* attributes of an svg created and manipulated with Raphael.js mean. I assumed they were the coordinates of the top-left corner of the object in relation to the canvas, but now I'm not so sure.

After creating a canvas (`var paper = new Raphael(container,width,height)`) and adding an image or rectangle to it, for example, if I retrieve the "x" and "y" attributes using the `attr` method (e.g. `object.attr("x")`), they're both at 0. However, if I rotate that object and then retrieve the values of x and y again, the values don't reflect the position of the top-left corner of my object in relation to the canvas anymore.

Can someone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fear @afaf12's answer complacently goes only half the distance.  He's absolutely correct that transformation logic occurs after the fundamental attributes of a given element and doesn't effect them, but it is certainly possible to retrieve the x and y of that element after transformations are applied.  You'll want to use the [getBBox](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.getBBox) method, like this:

```
var bbox = elem.getBBox();
console.log("Transformed coordinates of element are %s,%s", bbox.x, bbox.y );
```

Please note that there is some trickiness involved -- this returns the bounding box of the element, which is often a superset of the space occupied by the element -- so there's no guarantee that the returned point will be IN the element.

Another alternative occurs if you're using paths -- path.[getPointAtLength](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.getPointAtLength) also works with transformed coordinates, so you can get the x,y offset of the beginning of a path by calling

```
var coord = elem.getPointAtLength(0);
console.log("Transformed coordinates of path are %s,%s", coord.x, coord.y );
```

Answer (score 1):

Rotation is a transformation and it does not change x and y of the object.
http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.transform

Comment: I see what you mean, I must have missed that part, although this doesn't answer the question "What do 'x' and 'y' represent?" So what exactly are the x and y attributes of an svg element?